# The standard tropical lines - Pointwise valuation

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, tropical-geometry

Let $K$ be an algebraically closed field with valuation, and its value group $\Gamma_\text{val}^n$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$. Consider the polynomial
$
f(x,y)=x+y+1.
$
It can easy by shown that the tropical hypersurface  $V(\text{trop}(f))$ is the standard tropical lines
$
V(\text{trop}(f))=\{x=y \leq 0\} \cup \{x=0 \leq y\} \cup \{y=0\leq x\}.
$

I want to show that this is true from just taking pointwise valuation.
We have that
$
V(f)=\{(z,-1-1)\}.
$

note that $\text{in}_\mathbf{w}(f)$ is a monomial unless $\mathbf{w}$ is a non negative multipe of $(1,0),(0,1)$ or $(1,1)$. My problem becomes in showing/understanding that

$
(\text{val}(z),\text{val}(-1-z)=
\begin{cases}
(\text{val}(z),0), \ \text{if} \ \text{val}(z)>0 \\
(\text{val}(z),\text{val}(z),\ \text{val}(z) <0 \\
(0,\text{val}(z+1), \ \text{if} \ \text{val}(z)=0, \ \text{val}(z+1)>0\\
0, \quad \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$

is correct. I usually think of $K$ to be the Puiseux series.